# Python Class & Methods definition error with attributes - Request for Code Review

Tags: python, class, methods, attributes

I'm not an expert in Python and I'm not getting this to work. It is for a coding challenge to enter a new course, let's say 'academic purpose'

```
class ClaseVehiculo:
        def __init__(self,tipo,color):
            self.tipo = tipo
            self.color = color 
            self.velocidad = 0
            if not ( tipo in ['auto','camioneta','moto']) :
               print ( 'Tipo de vehiculo no reconocido. No se puede crear la clase: ClaseVehiculo.' )
               CANCEL
        @classmethod
        def Acelerar(self,variacion):
            self.velocidad += variacion
            if self.velocidad < 0:
                self.velocidad = 0
            if self.velocidad > 100:
                self.velocidad = 100
    return ClaseVehiculo

a = ClaseVehiculo('auto','verde')
print ( a )
print ( a.tipo() )
```

Apparently, 'a' is initialized as a ClaseVehiculo class but

when Print (a.tipo() )   'tipo' is not recognized as a class attribute

Comment: If that is the actual indentation of your program then that is one major problem that needs to be addressed.. Also CANCEL isn't really a thing.  Your use of classmethod appears to be wrong and tipo is a attribute property not a method so the brackets should throw an error.  I think the best advice is to read [this](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

`tipo` is an instance variable but you are calling it as an instance method. In Python, one accesses an instance variable without parenthesis (`a.tipo` in your case). The parenthesis is used in case you are calling an instance method.
You can read more about this in python docs :
[1]: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables